# How to apply GraphLayout to parts of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to sketch polymers. Here is how I do it for the monomer:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 1, 4 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can the left part arranged to form a **regular hexagon**? This is only a subunit so for polymers there are more. Is there a general way to do so? For the polymer, I wrote an ugly one:

```
Mol[k_] := Join[
   Table[Join[
     Table[(8 n + i) <-> (8 n + i + 1), {i, 5}],
     {(8 n + 6) <-> (8 n + 1), (8 n + 4) <-> (8 n + 7), (8 n + 7) <-> (8 n + 8),
      (8 n + 8) <-> (8 n + 9)}], {n, 0, k - 2}],
   Join[Table[(8 (k - 1) + i) <-> (8 (k - 1) + i + 1), {i, 5}],
     {(8 (k - 1) + 6) <-> (8 (k - 1) + 1), (8 (k - 1) + 4) <-> (8 (k - 1) + 7),
      (8 (k - 1) + 7) <-> (8 (k - 1) + 8)}]] // Flatten;

Graph[Mol[5], VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Have you tried `ChemicalData /@ ChemicalData["Polymers"]`?

Comment: A good point, but I'm going to use AdjacencyMatrix[] after this and apply Huckel model, so it's better to use Graph here.

Comment: It's not about being purist but there is a hexagon. You mean regular one?

Comment: Yes, a regular one. I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your code for making a polymer and show an example how it should look.

Comment: I have updated it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have given a new answer that uses VertexCoordinates instead of GraphLayout. This should provide you with what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use "SpringEmbedding" for GraphLayout:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 1, 4 <-> 7,
7 <-> 8}, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and reverse direction by reversing the whole structure

```
Graph[{8 <-> 7, 7 <-> 4, 1 <-> 6, 6 <-> 5, 5 <-> 4, 4 <-> 3, 3 <-> 2, 
2 <-> 1}, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:**

By generating a polymer chain using

```
Mol[k_] := 
Join[Table[{(8 + 8*i) <-> (7 + 8*i), (7 + 8*i) <-> (4 + 8*i), (1 + 
8*i) <-> (6 + 8*i), (6 + 8*i) <-> (5 + 8*i), (5 + 
8*i) <-> (4 + 8*i), (4 + 8*i) <-> (3 + 8*i), (3 + 
8*i) <-> (2 + 8*i), (2 + 8*i) <-> (1 + 8*i)}, {i, 0, k - 1}], 
Table[{(8 + 8*i) <-> (9 + 8*i)}, {i, 0, k - 1}]];
```

I get this for a length of 5:

```
Graph[Flatten@Mol[5], GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding",
ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By using InferentialDistance as a parameter the chain can be straightened to a certain degree:

```
Graph[Flatten@Mol[5], 
GraphLayout -> {"SpringEmbedding", "InferentialDistance" -> 1000}, 
ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this doesn't work for longer chains:

```
Graph[Flatten@Mol[50], 
GraphLayout -> {"SpringEmbedding", "InferentialDistance" -> 1000}, 
ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. It works for the unit, but when I make a polymer it fails.

Comment: Please provide your code for making a polymer and show an example how it should look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to your problem using VertexCoordinates:

The single unit is given by

```
single = {8 <-> 7, 7 <-> 4, 1 <-> 6, 6 <-> 5, 5 <-> 4, 4 <-> 3, 3 <-> 2, 2 <-> 1};
```

and the coordinates of the vertices are calculated with

```
singlecoords = 
Join[Table[(i + 1) -> {Sin[3/2*Pi + i*Pi/3], 
Cos[3/2*Pi + i*Pi/3]}, {i, 0, 5}], {7 -> {2, 0}, 8 -> {3, 0}}];
```

then you can plot the basic unit using

```
Graph[single, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
VertexCoordinates -> singlecoords, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we can generate a polymer of desired length with

```
Mol2[k_] := {Flatten[
Join[Table[{(8 + 8*i) <-> (7 + 8*i), (7 + 8*i) <-> (4 + 
8*i), (1 + 8*i) <-> (6 + 8*i), (6 + 8*i) <-> (5 + 
8*i), (5 + 8*i) <-> (4 + 8*i), (4 + 8*i) <-> (3 + 
8*i), (3 + 8*i) <-> (2 + 8*i), (2 + 8*i) <-> (1 + 8*i)}, {i,
0, k - 1}], Table[{(8 + 8*i) <-> (9 + 8*i)}, {i, 0, k - 2}]]],
Flatten[{Table[
Join[Table[(i + 1 + j*8) -> {Sin[3/2*Pi + i*Pi/3] + j*5, 
Cos[3/2*Pi + i*Pi/3]}, {i, 0, 
5}], {(7 + j*8) -> {2 + j*5, 0}, (8 + j*8) -> {3 + j*5, 
0}}], {j, 0, k - 1}]}]};
```

where the first element generates the vertices and the second element calculates the vertex coordinates.

For length 2 we get

```
polymer = Mol2[2];

Graph[polymer[[1]], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
VertexCoordinates -> polymer[[2]], ImagePadding -> 10, 
ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and for length 10 it looks like this:

```
polymer = Mol2[10];

Graph[polymer[[1]], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
VertexCoordinates -> polymer[[2]], ImagePadding -> 10, 
ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much.